# can't get response status code with JavaScript fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postman, fetch-api, http-status-codes

I'm trying to create a login form. when I'm testing the service with Postman, I will get a body object with status code and etc.

[image: Postman Result]

But, with JavaScript fetch, I can't get body object and I just received an error:

[image: fetch console log]

```
export const login = (username,password) => {
    return dispatch=>{
        const basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
        let myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append('Authorization', basicAuth);
            myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
            fetch(`${baseUrl}api/user/login`, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: myHeaders
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (json) {
                dispatch(setLoginInfo(json))
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err)
                 dispatch(loginFailed())
            });
    }

}
```

I need to get status code in fetch.

Comment: You got a CORS error here … so go read up on what that means, and what needs to be done to fix it.

Comment: I put the answer here please check. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940824/12553450

Comment: you can try this: `async function fetchText() {
    let response = await  fetch('url.php');

    console.log(response.status); // 200
    console.log(response.statusText); // OK

    if (response.status === 200) {
        let data = await response.text();
        console.log(data);
    }
}`

Answer (score 65):

The status code is the [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) property on the response object. Also, unless you're using JSON with your **error** responses (which some people do, of course), you need to check the status code (or the [`ok` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok)) before calling `json`:

```
fetch(`${baseUrl}api/user/login`, {
    credentials: "include", // ¹ See note below
    headers: myHeaders
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status); // Will show you the status
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(// ...
```

Not checking that the request succeeded is such a common mistake I [wrote it up on my anemic old blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

---

¹ You had `withCredentials: true`, but [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) says it's `credentials: "include"`. (Thank you [aderchox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9868445/aderchox) for pointing that out.)

Comment: when my request gets failed, nothing in .then() will run. it goes straight to catch()

Comment: @alimottaghian - The promise from `fetch` only rejects on **network errors**, not HTTP errors. So it will reject if you can't send the request to the server, but it does not reject if the server responds with (say) a 404.

Comment: With ES6 fetch use: `credentials: 'include'` and not `withCredentials: true`.

Comment: @aderchox - Thanks for pointing that out! I just copied what the OP had, but you're right. I've flagged that up in the answer as well. (Side note: `fetch` has nothing to do with "ES6", it's the web platform, not JavaScript.)

Answer (score 10):

The `status` is present in the `response` object. You can get it inside your first then block

```
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    return response.json();
})
```

Since you are returning `response.json()`, the subsequent `then` and `catch` only gets the result of `response.json()` which  is the body of the response.

Comment: when my request gets failed, nothing in .then() will run. it goes straight to catch()

Comment: you can try return response.text() instead, i got exactly the same issue, going directly to catch then i realize ir was the response

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940824/12553450